# EXM Experience Editing - missing create new content

Tags: presentation

I've created a new rendering and have set the Datasource Location and Datasource Template.  However when I add it to a placeholder inside the EXM Experience Editor I only see the option to select Existing Content - I cannot create a new content item.

[image]

[image]

What have I missed setting such that I can add a new content block into my email with a datasource item created?

Using Sitecore 9.1.1.

**Update:** Have reproduced this in a vanilla instance of Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1 using the sample newsletter template.

Comment: Hey @Jen , is this happening as an admin user? It may be permissions related?

Comment: @GeorgeTucker Yes - am logged in as an administrator :(

Comment: @GeorgeTucker Strangely when testing the sample newsletter, when I select a rendering to add to it again I don't see an option to Create new content item.  Hopefully hear back from Support soon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug - reference number 355958.  The issue was related to the fact that sxa data-source selection dialog overrides default dialog for EXM(non-sxa) site.

Hotfix available from Sitecore support.